# Invalid Resource or Resource[id] does not exist keycloak

Tags: authorization, keycloak, keycloak-authorization-services

I have deleted one resource, policy, and permission from keycloak because its a replica of another resource with a different name but now for that URL keycloak gets deleted resource and trying to find out deleted resource rather than existing one hence that gives me an error from java **Invalid error and Resource[id] does not exist**. I have checked the database also I couldn't find the resource id anywhere.

```
Unexpected response from server: 400 / Bad Request / Response from server: {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"Resource with id [5d72c149-c56d-49e6-8c01-da58020a0d9b] does not exist."}
```

Comment: Maybe revert and delete the other one?

Comment: revert ?? how would I do that?

Comment: Well, don't you have an exported JSON configuration of your deleted resource?